# LightGBM model dumped in PMML format gives different predictions from the original model

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, lightgbm, pmml

I want to use a sklearn model in pyspark.

I have trained a lightGBM model (in sklearn) which gives out probabilities for a propensity problem.
Then converted this model to PMML format like this:

```py
from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml
sklearn2pmml(trained_model, 'prod_trained_model.pmml')
```

And then in pyspark, I read the PMML model like this:

```py
from pypmml_spark import ScoreModel
model_pipeline = ScoreModel.fromFile('prod_trained_model.pmml')
```

Then I make predictions like this ('features_df' is a pyspark dataframe):

```py
predictions_df = model_pipeline.transform(features_df)
```

Now the problem is that the model predictions do not match with those of original model. There is a shift of 5% to 10% in the predicted probabilities.

Also for around 5% of the rows in input dataframe, the output probabilities by PMML model are NaN. Whereas for the exact same rows, the original model is predicting fine.

Comment: What exactly has Pyspark to do here? Are you actually taking a scikit-learn model and, via PMML, using it to make predictions in Pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with missing / `null` values.

PMML models **do not process nulls** the same way as your model.

This is the reason why you should be using `.fillna()` to impute missing values.